Proving a point preserving compactness of subsets is a limit point
Let B be an infinite set in $\mathbb{R}$. (Countable or uncountable - we are not given any more details).
Let $p \in \mathbb{R}$ be a point such that for every subset $C \subseteq B$ we have $C \cup \{p\}$ is compact. Prove that $p \in \bar B$.
Would appreciate any directionns on approaching this. In particular do I need to make use of the metric structure on $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. using distance, sup and the likes) or can I approach this with purely topological arguments?
If $p \in B$ obviously it is a limit point of $B$ in particular and therefore it is in its closure, so I assume $p \notin B$ and then I need to show its a limit point. I thought of trying to construct some downward closed series ($K_{i+1} \subseteq K_i$) of compact sets of the form $B_i \cup p$ for $B_i \subseteq B$ which are all compact based on the data we are given, and therefore I can make use of a lemma which states their intersection in particular is compact and non-empty. But not sure if that leads me to something useful?

$p$ must either be an isolated point of $B$ or a limit point of $B$. Consider those two cases separately.

First note that $B\cup\{p\}$ is compact so in particular it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. We have that $B$ can only have isolated points since if $y\in B$ were a limit point then there would be a sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $B\setminus\{y\}$ which converges to $y$. This would imply that $(B\setminus\{y\})\cup\{p\}$ would not be closed and therefore could not be compact. So every point in $B$ is isolated and so it must be countable since $\mathbb{R}$ is separable. We have that $\{p\}$ must be the only limit point of $B\cup\{p\}$ so in particular you have that $p\in \overline{B}$.

I ended up with the following argument, very similar to what Giorgio Genovesi's answer above:
Since B is infinite we can define an infinite sequence $(x_i)$ of elements in B which are all distinct ($x_i \neq x_j$ for all $i \neq j$).
Since $B \cup p$ is compact, in particular it is bounded therefore this sequence has a converging subsequence, and since $B \cup p$ is also in particular closed, the limit point of this sequence is in $B \cup p$, lets call it $y$.
Now assume $y \neq p$. We define the set B' = $ (B-\{y\}) \cup \{p\}$ and observe that this set is compact as well according to the data - in contradiction to the fact that there is a sequence of points converging to $y$ in this compact set and $y$ is not in it (here we make use of the fact the sequence we defined earlier is made of distinct elements, that is even after removing y this sequence is left intact in B'). Therefore, necessarily $y = p$, that is p is a limit point of B (and in fact the only one under this data).
